# How to use browser content provider?

Tags: android, browser, android-contentprovider

I have written this simple code to get the bookmarks from the browser:

```
public class BroswerProviderActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, null, null, null, null);

        String s[] = new String[]{
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK,
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE};
        int view[] = new int[]{
                R.id.Bookmark, R.id.title};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, s, view);

        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I also added the permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS">
```

But when i am running this app, it is not working. It displays some error and asks to Force Stop the application. What is the problem with this? please help me out. Thank you

Here is the exception i am getting from the LogCat window. But this is unrelated:[image]

Here is the xml file that i wrote:

```
<ListView android:transcriptMode="normal" android:id="@+id/list"     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0"></ListView>
 <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/bookmark" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
 <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

Comment: Since you are getting a "Force close" dialog: Please post the stacktrace from your logcat. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterKnego please see the exception i got in the LogCat

Comment: @alextsc i got the above exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ListActivity` the ID of the `ListView` in your layout XML *must* be `@android:id/list`.

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Comment: Thank you. Its working. But i cant get it why? I used @+id/list for the same program while using Contacts content provider. Why doesn't it support the same syntax here

Comment: You probably use a normal Activity instead of a ListActivity there - or make no use of `setContentView()`. The reason is simple. The ListActivity uses `findViewById()` internally with this id hardcoded. If you set a layout by yourself it searches it, and can't find it in this case. If you don't set the layout by yourself, it just add's a ListView with this id as the layout on it's own.

Comment: @alextsc I have double checked the code i wrote for Contact content provider. Everything is same as the above code's structure.

Comment: Mhm ok. I can only guess around at this point without seeing the code, so if you are interested, please post that code *(maybe at pastebin or a similar service to avoid cluttering this solved question)*.